# Townhall placement in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

Why do some profesional Clash of Clans players place their Townhall way beyond their defenses and outside their walls, from where it can be easily destroyed?

Won't the attacking player easily get a two star even without much strategy by decimating the Townhall and getting a 50% destruction afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

While the Townhall is an important structure and gives a star if destroyed, in many of the top clans, wars come down to how many 3 stars your clan can get. Therefore most top players build anti-three-star bases and forgo trying to protect their townhall allowing for a basically free 2 star raid on their base in hopes that they won't get 3 starred.

At townhall 11+, the townhall itself becomes a fairly decent defense in its own right with the tesla. Treating it as a defense instead of a VIP to protect allows for different base designs that take advantage of its hard-hitting multi-target Tesla.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons of it. Dragonrage describe the first reason but he didnt tell the other reason so let me tell you the other reason. The other reason is they want to protect their resources like gold, elixir, dark elixir. That is why they place townhall out side the walls or on very weak place or on the edge of the village. and place gold storage, elixir storage and dark elixir storage in the middle of the base. And put some strong defenses around your resources storage. By doing this your enemy just get 1 star or 2 star but he didnt destroy the whole base and he didnt get the loot from your base. So these kinda bases are [anti 3 star clash of clans bases](https://bestcocmaps.com/). He only earn some trophies. So when ever you want to save your loot just put townhall on weak place and secure your resources on a strong place.